# How to get the array of object instead of just _id in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql

I am very new to mongoose.
I am currently building a backend using Node.js, express.js, GraphQL, and mongoose.
I have a Drink schema and DrinkType Schema. I defined DrinkType schema as "alcohol", "juice", "tea". And I have added many drinks and each drink has DrinkType reference. Then, I would like to reference all the drinks from DrinkType.
This is the schema for drinkType

```js
const drinkTypeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  createdDrinks: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Drink',
    },
  ],
```

Here is the schema for drink

```js
const drinkSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  drinkType: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'DrinkType',
  },
})
```

This is the drink resolver. Whenever a new drink is created, I am pushing it to drinkType.

```js
try {
      const result = await drink.save()
      createdDrink = transformDrink(result)
      const drinkType = await DrinkType.findById(args.addDrinkInput.drinkTypeId)
      if (!drinkType) {
        throw new Error('DrinkType not found.')
      }
      drinkType.createdDrinks.push(drink)
      await drinkType.save()
```

```js
const drinkLoader = new DataLoader(drinkIds => {
  return drinks(drinkIds)
})

const drinks = async drinkIds => {
  try {
    const drinks = await Drink.find({ _id: { $in: drinkIds } })
    return drinks.map(drink => {
      return transformDrink(drink)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
}

const transformDrink = drink => {
  return {
    ...drink._doc,
    _id: drink.id,
    drinkType: drinkType.bind(this, drink.drinkType),
  }
}


const drinkType = async drinkTypeId => {
  try {
    const drinkType = await drinkTypeLoader.load(drinkTypeId.toString())
    return {
      ...drinkType._doc,
      _id: drinkType.id,
      createdDrinks: () => drinkLoader.loadMany(drinkType._doc.createdDrinks),
    }
```

I want this createdDrinks part to return the array of drink objects, but it is only returning the array of _ids.

I have been reading the mongoose documentation and it seems that using ObjectId is the correct way. Would you mind helping me out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to pass some data that what you want to create. An example `let drink = new drink(yourobj); let result = await drink.save()` and you Will get some result

Comment: Yes, but that's the operation we use when we are creating new data, right? The data already existed in MongoDB in my case.